# SQL create an alias or typedef for varchar(20)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to standardize our mysql table creation script, we have several similar names that perform similar function in several tables.

Think the column name is owner, creator, updater and it appears in multiple tables. But some tables are using the datatype as varchar(20), some are using varchar(50) and some varchar(100).

Is there a way to standardize these datatypes by using an alias or typedef of some kind ?

Example, instead of creating tables in my sql script create-tables.sql like :

```
create table A ( owner varchar(20) );
create table B ( creator varchar(50) );
create table C ( updater varchar(100) );
```

I do something like :

```
alias datatype_name is varchar(20)
create table A ( owner datatype_name );
create table B ( creator datatype_name );
create table C ( updater datatype_name );
```

Of course in MySQL these tables can use the data type varchar(20) , I am certainly not expecting the alias to carry forward from the creation sql script to mysql.

Comment: No, I don't think MySQL has type aliases.

Comment: You could do it by preprocessing your table creation script with a macro processor like `m4`.

Comment: You can actually do this in SQL Server, although you wouldn't want to as the implementation is awful.

Comment: PostgreSQL also has a feature to create a domain as a named type: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html But MySQL does not have a similar feature.